# Winsock TCP Packets sent but not reaching host

Tags: tcp, client-server, winsock, winsock2

When the server sends 4 or more - 25 Byte packets to the client only the first 2 are processed by the client. I am using Event select on the client, and send on the server. There are no errors but only the first 2 packets are displayed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to show some code...

Comment: Have you tried to catch this traffic using Wireshark and check what's going on? Maybe your messages are concatenated or split, but in your code you don't handle this correctly. All of this will be visible in Wireshark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at your code I can only think of one issue that you might be overlooking,

Maybe you are missing a point that TCP is a stream based protocol. If you send data by calling Send function 10 times from client then it is not necessary that you have to call the receive function 10 times on receiving side. All data maybe retrieved in 1 receive or 5 or 8 or 12 receives. I mean don't try to look at it in form of packets. You have to do Framing yourself to identify the packets.

When you send 4 packets of 25 byte each. The total is 100 byte data.
On receiving side you may be getting 2 packets of 50 bytes and you have to identify your packets yourself by using some start and end markers etc...

You can also get a single packet of 100 bytes or 10 packets of 10 bytes. keep that in mind.